# Iphone 5s stuck in headphone mode

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I have a pair of Sol headphones that would always fit into my iphone until recently I realized that my iPhone didn't have any sound coming out of the internal speakers.

It was my headphone jack that is causing the issues and i just cleaned it out but now its not working and the sol headphones I mention just don't fit into my iPhone. I barely get the tip in and nothing else can go through and im not trying to force it in.

How do i fix this?

Comment: How did you clean it?

Answer (score 2):

If there is nothing physically jammed into the headphone jack then it should be easily fixable.

This happens to me occasionally when sound refuses to play out the external speakers and the simplest solution is to **restart your phone** by holding down the sleep button until it says *slide to power off*. Then, restart it by either plugging it in to a power source or holding the sleep button for an extended few seconds.

On the other hand if this doesn't work and the piece logged in there is the problem, try cleaning out the jack using things such as **tweezers** or **compressed air**. If all else fails, turn it in the the nearest Apple Store ( via in person or by mail ) and have them take a look at the device in person.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

Solution that worked for me -  the simplest way is to **schedule an alarm** which will trigger **after 10 or 15 mins** and do a **hard reset** by pressing the home button and the power button at the same time. Once the alarm gets triggered , let it go on for **5 or 10 mins**, after that click on the **volume up / down button** to see whether **ringer volume pop up** is displayed instead of headphones. If it is getting displayed immediately open your **music app** and play a song to see that the sound is redirected to the speaker.

Answer (score -2):

First solution: Perform a soft reset/reboot your iPhone 
Second solution: Reset all settings on your iPhone
Third solution: RecoveryTool Fix Recovery